# Regex javascript allow only numbers, alphabets and underscore

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using this code to prevent people from puting spaces between alphabets and numbers. I would lilke to modify the code so that only alphabets, letters and numbers can be typed.

This is what i'm doing:

```
 replace(/\sg, '') oin javascript
```

Can anyone help me as to how to costrucrt the regex expression so that only alphavets, nnumbers, underscore and no space can be keyed in the input box

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to learn how to compose regular expressions?

Comment: Please, take a look at the update [here](http://jsfiddle.net/r4fY5/1/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how you could do it with jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $( '#username' ).on( 'keydown', function( e ) {
        if( !$( this ).data( "value" ) )
             $( this ).data( "value", this.value );
    });
    $( '#username' ).on( 'keyup', function( e ) {
        if (!/^[_0-9a-z]*$/i.test(this.value))
            this.value = $( this ).data( "value" );
        else
            $( this ).data( "value", null );
    });
});
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/r4fY5/1/) Demo

Comment: this is good, but if you hold the space bar or a character key down, you can get past it and it wont prevent characters from being entered...out of curiosity is there a way to prevent that?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you want something like this:

```
var input = "f%o@o";
var output = input.replace(/\W/g, ''); // "foo"
```

This will remove any **non**-word character (a word character is a letter, number, or underscore) from the `input` string.

Comment: I actually just want leters, numbers and unserscore to be in the input. So I guess the opposite

Comment: @KwaasiDjin That's what this will do. It will remove **non**-word characters.

Comment: yeah but this includes symbolds like @#$%^&*, however, i just want underscore letters and numbers

Comment: @KwaasiDjin Please see the example. `"f%o@o".replace(/\W/g, '')` becomes `"foo"`.